# radio buttons are not displaying in the webpage

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

Am trying to add some radio buttons in a jsp form.It is using spring mvc architecture.Am new to this.

.But after adding the radio buttons the web page is not displaying anything in the form.
Whats wrong with my code..

```
welcome
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/job_trigger.css">

<style>
.display TH {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FDEEF4;
    font-family: arial;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.display TD {
    font-family: arial;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
<form:form id="jobTriggerForm" name="jobTriggerForm"
    action="jobTrigger.htm" modelAttribute="jobTriggerForm" method="POST">

    <div id="jobTriggerDiv">
    // Not showing anything in the page after adding the below radio buttons..so i commented
    <%-- <table align= 'center'>
        <form:radiobutton path="testplan" value="1Hour" />
        1 Hour <br />
        <form:radiobutton path="testplan" value="4Hour" />
        4 Hour <br />
        <form:radiobutton path="testplan" value="2day" />
        2 Day <br />
        <form:radiobutton path="testplan" value="AED" />
        AED <br />
        <form:radiobutton path="testplan" value="Component" />
        Component

</table> --%>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

Comment: is there any error in eclipse console ?

Comment: isn't it `<form:radio>`?